# You put in the wrong leg

Tags: word-usage, grammar

He put his feet in the same leg.

> "You put in the wrong leg."

I told him.

Would it confuse the leg meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by @Ringo, both sentences are correct.

> He put his feet in the same leg.

means

> He put his feet in the same [trouser] leg.

Whereas

> "You put in the wrong leg."

means

> "You put in the wrong [person's] leg [in the trouser leg]"

However, using both close together like this can be confusing. It may be better to explicitly state which leg is being referred to, or use the word foot, like so:

> He put his feet in the same trouser leg.
>
> "You put in the wrong foot."

Note the response could also be:

> "You put your foot in the wrong leg"

The difference in interpretation between this response and your original response is minor, but makes it clear the 'foot' is the person's and the 'leg' must be the trouser's, because it is being 'put into'.

Answer (score 1):

***Leg*** can mean a person's appendage or the leg of a pair of pants. It's perfectly fine to say the following:

> You put your foot in the wrong leg.
>
> You have both feet in the same leg.

Comment: What do those sentences mean?

Comment: @dan - It means the person has done [this](http://images.obesityhelp.com/uploads/profile/933781/albums/114395/capris%20-%20mai%202013%20-%20165%20lbs.jpg).